# VSCode: Request connection/GetChildrenForTreeItemRequest failed, ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, vscode-extensions

I use Visual Studio Code and the MSSQL extension to connect to the Azure server & database.

While it confirms the connection is made, I cannot see its children, like tables and when I attempt to see them, I get an error from the extension

The error is:

> Request connection/GetChildrenForTreeItemRequest failed with message:
> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

I've checked whether my IP is not blocked by the firewall

Answer (score 0):

There is a firewall on the Azure application itself. You'll have to add your Ip address on your Azure application. Go to your project => overview => Set server firewall, then just add your ip address to it.

Comment: You are right! I could connect with Visual Studio Full and it said there's a missing IP to whitelist for the Firewall. Yet the same error occurs in VSCode